# How do I delete columns in a dataframe if the name begins with X?

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I delete all columns in an `R` dataframe whose names begin with `X`?

Here is how I want it to look (before and after):

```
Before:

¦ 1COL1 ¦ 2COL ¦ 3COL ¦ XCOL ¦ 4COL ¦ XXCOL ¦

After:

¦ 1COL1 ¦ 2COL ¦ 3COL ¦ 4COL ¦
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the column whose name begin with `X` using `grep` and with its `invert` property set as `TRUE`. With `invert = TRUE` it returns the indices which don't match the given pattern.

```
df_1 <- df[grep("^X", colnames(df), invert = TRUE)]
```

---

This can also be done with `grepl` which returns logical vector.

```
df[!grepl("^X", colnames(df))]
```